# Auto horizontal splash screen

Tags: android, view, splash-screen

stackoverflow people. I've currently have this app that im developing, where I would like to make my splash screen automatically turn to horizontal view, when the app starts, and not to be any other view then horizontal.
But just for the 3 seconds my splash screen runs.

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to your splash screen's activity.